# Which CSS selector to use to select the first letter of the element with id?

Tags: css

Which CSS selector to use to select the first letter of the element with id?
I want to make the first letter of the element with id 'special' green and 100px font size.
I tried :

```
#special:nth-of-type(1){
    color: green;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a `::first-letter` pseudoselector

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

```css
#special::first-letter {
  color: green;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p id="special">This is a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you Rich.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to flag this as answered

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. The answer above is correct. For further information, read the following on https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

"21. X::pseudoElement

```
p::first-line {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

We can use pseudo elements (designated by ::) to style fragments of an element, such as the first line, or the first letter. Keep in mind that these must be applied to block level elements in order to take effect.

A pseudo-element is composed of two colons: ::

Target the First Letter of a Paragraph

```
p::first-letter {
float: left;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: cursive;
padding-right: 2px;
}
```

This snippet is an abstraction that will find all paragraphs on the page, and then sub-target only the first letter of that element.

This is most often used to create newspaper-like styling for the first-letter of an article.

Target the First Line of a Paragraph

```
p::first-line {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Similarly, the ::first-line pseudo element will, as expected, style the first line of the element only."

If you want to select the first letter of the element with id, simply add a "#" in order to select it. It goes like this:

```
#insertnameofyouridhere::first-line {
       color: blue;
       font-size: 20px;
    }
```